# Can't get json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to get city name from input element and then get the weather information and also timezone information of the city from API. 
However i can't get the json object in that function but it works outside the function.
Can anyone help me?

```js
var d = "Lisbon";
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    d = document.getElementById("input").value;
    $(document).ready(function myfunction() {
      $.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=11d324c05e02e308c1c9eb8d8041b143&q=' + d + '&units=metric', function(data) {
        document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = data.name + ", " + data.sys.country;
        document.getElementById("wind").innerHTML = data.wind.speed + " m/s  ";
        document.getElementById("cloudiness").innerHTML = data.weather[0].description;
        document.getElementById("pressure").innerHTML = data.main.pressure + " hpa";
        document.getElementById("humidity").innerHTML = data.main.humidity + " %";
        document.getElementById("coord").innerHTML = "[ " + data.coord.lat + ", " + data.coord.lon + " ]";
        document.getElementById("temperature").innerHTML = data.main.temp + "°C";
        document.getElementById("icon").innerHTML = "<img src=http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + data.weather[0].icon + ".png" + ">";
        console.log(data);
        (function() {
          $.getJSON("http://api.geonames.org/timezoneJSON?" + "lat=" + data.coord.lat + "&" + "lng=" + data.coord.lon + "&username=hrrs", function(data) {
            document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = data.time;
            document.getElementById("timeCity").innerHTML = data.timezoneId;
            document.getElementById("country").innerHTML = data.countryName;
            document.getElementById("sunrise").innerHTML = data.sunrise;
            document.getElementById("sunset").innerHTML = data.sunset;
            console.log(data);
          });
        })();
      });
      document.getElementById("slayt").innerHTML = '<iframe src="http://www.panoramio.com/wapi/template/slideshow.html?tag=' + d + '&amp;width=1920&amp;height=500&amp;" frameborder="0" width="1920" height="500" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"></iframe>';

    })();
  });
});
```

Comment: It would be good form to show your javascript and html code in any service. For example, in http://jsfiddle.net/? And indicate where exactly the problem.

Comment: can you explain why, in line 5, you use $(document).ready again?

Comment: @schudel it shouldn't be there i changed it. I tried that function outside of the $("#button").click(function() to see if getJSON works or not. getJSON works by itself but not in that function. I don't get why it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?
http://jsfiddle.net/wnunhhac/

```
<input type="text" id="inputCity" value="Zurich"/>
<input type="button" id="start" value="Go" />   
<br />
<span id="city">click go</span>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#start").click(function() {
      var d = $("#inputCity").val();
      $.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=11d324c05e02e308c1c9eb8d8041b143&q=' + d + '&units=metric', function(data) {
        $("#city").html(data.name);          
      });
    });
});
```

The API returns status code 404 not found, if the city is invalid. So you should code an appropriate resonse.

```
if (data.cod === "404") {
  // Api could not find city
  return;
}
```

Also I changed the button type to "button" instead of "submit"

```
<button type="button" id="button" class="btn btn-default">
```

Corresponding Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xvn6f05w/

Comment: thank you, when i changed the button type, it is solved. But I don't understand why submit is not working.

Comment: Since you have a form and do not use preventDefault() in your click-handler, clicking the button essentially does two things: 1) start your button handler and 2) post back the form to the server. If you do not care about graceful degredation, you could do without the form altogether. Hope this makes sense.